# Angular - passing endpoint to http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I know that this code won't work. I'm working on a project where for each subject I'm writting all the grades. So it was fairly easy to get the lessons alone. But how to get grades for each independent lesson?

```
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div  ng-controller="u_p">
            <table ng-repeat="x in lessons">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                    {{x.subjectName}}
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a ng-controller="u_c" model="{{x.id}}"> <!--THIS PART-->
                            {{x.idSubject}} <!-- no ng-repeat for now-->
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>                
            </table>   
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

And the angular part

```
app.controller("u_c", function($scope,$http,$attrs){
    $http({
        url: IP+"/Grades/myPartialGrades/"+$attrs.model,
        method: "GET", 
        headers: {
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Authorization":"token",
                },
    }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.grades = data.data.grades;

    }),(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
});
```

That's what I figured out of other topics on this subject, but couldn't find a way to resolve my own.

## edit

Figured that my question wasn't well formulated.
I wanted to use model to pass the "id" of a subject, so I could extract grades from certain lessons. The way I would be getting grades is "/Grades/myPartialGrades/(ID OF A LESSONS)". But to get the id of a lesson I need to extract it (I'm using x.id here).
However - I couldn't make it work with passing through "model" as shown in my example because "model" simply passes string.
So in a nutshell: I'm using ng-repeat to show every lesson. Every lesson has it's own "id" and to ask for grades I need to perform a query which at the end of the url has the "id" of a subject. And I have no idea how else could I pass this information that my controller would put at the end of url.

Comment: It depends on your data structure, what is the relationship between lessons and grades? Can you show us the data structure of lessons? (is it in data.grades?)

Comment: Don't say the code "doesn't work" and leave it at that. Describe the problem.

Comment: The sensible approach is to have the controller outside the `ng-repeat` fetch the grades for each of the lessons in the lesson list. Using `ng-repeat` to instantiate controllers to do individual fetching tangles the concerns of Model and View. It makes the app difficult to understand, test, and maintain.

Comment: @AKMorris Lessons and grades are to different things. But if I want to ask for grades for a particular lesson(subject) I need to add the "id" of it at the end of my query (endpoint) which here would be at the end of URL.